# Installed Android Emulator (HAXM) on Azure VM

Tags: android, azure

We have one VM at Azure cloud. We want to run the android emulator in android studio and we are using Android Studio(3.5) for development purposes.
But while we try to install HAXM to run the android emulator on the android studio I'm facing the error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VTx is the Intel Virtualization Extensions for running virtualized workloads.  Microsoft use Hyper-V as their hypervisor, on top of which you create virtual machines.  HAXM / Android Emulator is a hypervisor itself and so what your trying to achieve is known as *nested virtualization*.

In order to use nested virtualization you need to select a VM size which supports it, such as D3_v3.

Please refer to this article for detailed instructions and considerations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization

NOTE: You don't need to install Hyper-V.  The article is written for using nested Hyper-V.

Comment: Thanks, please see that i am already using Standard D3 v2 (4 vcpus, 14 GiB memory) size on Azure, Further, i have removed the HYPER-v feature.Still facing error.

Comment: The v2 D-series doesn't support nesting.  `***Size:*** D1_v2 - D15_v2 ***ACU/vCPU:*** 210 - 250 ***Ratio:*** 1:1` It's missing the three asterisks.  Try the D4_v3 instead.  It should be cheaper too.