# How do I run Android virtual device in Azure VM?

Tags: android-studio, testing, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, azure-virtual-machine

I need the ability to run the Android emulator on a VM as part of a test environment to automate UI testing for a mobile app.

I have created my Azure VM:

OS: **Windows 10 Pro**

Size: **Standard D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)** to enable nested virtualisation (running a virtual device inside another virtual device with is the Azure VM).

Android Studio: **Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1**

I have installed Android Studio with HAXM installed after I disabled Hyper - V(since both cannot co-exisit and I was advised by somewhere that this is the correct procedure).

I am able to create the virtual device but when I try to start it I get the following error:

```
Emulator is ruuning nested virtualization. This si not recommended. It may not work at all


Your driver information:

GPU#1
Make: 1414
Model: Microsoft Basic Render Driver
DeviceID: 008c

Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.As a result, we're selecting a compatability renderer.
Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available
```

[image]

The virtual device is not able to start up,
Any ideas?

Comment: I tried in Windows 10 Pro with size Standard D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory) Gen-1 , its working for me, kindly try with Gen-1.

Comment: @VenkatV How is the emulator's performance in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I run Android virtual device in Azure VM?

I have followed the steps below to install Android Studio and an emulator in an Azure VM.

1. Created Azure VM - **Windows 10 Pro** with size **Standard D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)** and **Gen-1** not version **Gen-2**.

[image]

> Note: The v2 D-series doesn't support nesting, kindly use V1 version instead of Gen-V2

2. Installed [HAXM](https://www.filehorse.com/download-intel-haxm/download/)
3. Installed Android Studio, and once the Studio is installed, check the following settings in Android Studio by navigating through the steps below
   **Toos > SDK Manager > Languages & Framework >Android SDK > SDK Tools**
   [image]

4.Created `Virtual Device` as below.

[image]

5. After creating the device, I am able to launch the AVD successfully.

[image]

Refer same kind of issue in [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605791/installed-android-emulator-haxm-on-azure-vm) by  `Architect Jamie`and [Stack link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614055/not-able-to-install-haxm-in-azure-vm/76619309#76619309)

Comment: Still getting the same error when created VM with 'Gen 1'

Comment: Can you please share error snap, what you are getting?

Comment: Error message is in the original post above

Comment: Try this command: Set-VMProcessor -VMName "" -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true , follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484893/android-emulator-and-nested-virtualization)

Comment: Yes, I saw that link where do I run the script?
 I tried running it via the portal and I get the following: 

PS /home/slai6> Set-VMProcessor -VMName 'TestVM' -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
Set-VMProcessor: The term 'Set-VMProcessor' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Sorry, I'm a bit new Azure VM stuff :)

Comment: Shut down the VM, open Azure PowerShell, and run the command.

Comment: When you say open Azure Powershell are you referring to the button on the op right of the portal? I have done that and got the error:  "The term 'Set-VMProcessor' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. "

Comment: Go to your VM in portal and open Run command and try to execute the same.

Comment: Tried that and got the same error as above

Comment: If module is not installed, if you will get the same error, follow the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmprocessor?view=windowsserver2022-ps) for further reference.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - when we install HAXM Hyper-V must be disabled as both cannot co-exist together?

Comment: Here is the post from Microsoft explaining this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1105011/is-there-any-way-to-run-android-virtual-device-on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the prompt resonse Venkat.

I have followed you instructions but I m getting the exactly the same issue when I create the VM with 'Gen 1':

[image]

[image]

I have installed the following SDK tools:

[image]
[image]